# Unable to Save Generated Data to JSONL File - Always Resulting in "Wrote 0 examples to finetuning_events.jsonl" Message

Tags: natural-language-processing, chatgpt, open-ai, fine-tuning

#### Issue Description

When attempting to generate JSONL data using Llama Index, the process works well until the final step where the results are saved to a JSONL file. However, every time I try to save the data, it seems to be unsuccessful as I always receive the message "Wrote 0 examples to finetuning_events.jsonl". I am unsure of the reason behind this issue.

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Successfully generated JSONL data using Llama Index.
2. Attempted to save the results to a JSONL file.
3. Received the message "Wrote 0 examples to finetuning_events.jsonl".

#### Additional Information

- Llama Index version used: 0.10.22
- Operating System: Windows

#### Log

`Wrote 0 examples to ./dataset_data/finetuning_events.jsonl`

My code:

````
     def jsonl_generation(self):
        """
        Generate JSONL file for fine-tuning events and perform model refinement.
        """
        # Initialize OpenAI FineTuningHandler and CallbackManager
        finetuning_handler = OpenAIFineTuningHandler()
        callback_manager = CallbackManager([finetuning_handler])

        self.llm.callback_manager = callback_manager

        # Load questions for fine-tuning from a file
        questions = []
        with open(f'{self.dataset_path}/train_questions.txt', "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
            for line in f:
                questions.append(line.strip())

        try:
            # Generate responses to the questions using GPT-4 and save the fine-tuning events to a JSONL file
            index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
                self.documents
            )
            query_engine = index.as_query_engine(similarity_top_k=2, llm=self.llm)
            for question in questions:
                response = query_engine.query(question)
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle the exception here, you might want to log the error or take appropriate action
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        finally:
            # Save the fine-tuning events to a JSONL file
            finetuning_handler.save_finetuning_events(f'{self.dataset_path}/finetuning_events.jsonl')
```
````